# How to access published Excel, XML and Json file in dxa 2.0

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-2.0

We are using SDL Web 8.5 and DXA Java 2.0. We are publishing the bulk of JSON, XML, EXCEL file into broker database in a particular Structure Group but while accessing those file inside DXA java application we are not getting any response.

Answer (score 3):

The DXA Page Controller (which handles most URLs) assumes that the underlying Page Model data is published in either DXA R2 or DD4T JSON format. It is not able to serve other formats.

So-called *Static Content Items* are expected to have URLs which start with the *Multimedia URL* configured on the CM Publications. These can be in any format and are published and served as binary data (by the `StaticContentItemInterceptor`).

If you want to serve binary files which are published in a Structure Group, you will have to create your own Controller to serve those.

Comment: can u please give some example how to create own controller

Comment: For example: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-flexible-campaign-content/blob/master/java/campaigncontent-dxa-module/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/modules/campaigncontent/controller/CampaignAssetController.java